# Which slicer (Voxelizer or Cura) for Zmorph printer?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, g-code

Can I use Cura generated G-codes in Zmorph 3D printer?

Zmorph comes with its own slicing software (Voxelizer) but it only takes a 2D drawing as input and layer height is the only parameter that can be changed so that the entire 2D drawing increases in height. I wanted to print objects as shown here:

[image: Curved shapes]

I tried to create G-code in Cura and later use in Zmorph but the nozzle was going below the print bed when print is given so that I have to abort the print.

**Voxelizer code example (starting)**

```
; Generated with Voxelizer 2
;; { "info": [
;;         { "toolhead": "Thick Paste" },
;;         { "workflow": "chocolate\\ceramics" },
;;         { "voxelizer_version": "v2.0.0-macOS-1-g90eaae" },
;;         { "voxel_size": 0.23999999463558197 },
;;         { "printing_time": "6min 30s " },
;;         { "printer": "ZMorph VX" }
;;     ] }
G92 E0.00000
G1 E-2.00000 F3000.000
G1 Z3.160 F3000.000
G1 X99.257 Y97.462 F7200.000
G1 Z1.160 F3000.000
G1 E0.00000 F3000.000
G1 X99.225 Y97.435 E0.00046 F600.000
G1 X99.193 Y97.408 E0.00092 F600.000
G1 X99.162 Y97.381 E0.00138 F600.000
G1 X99.131 Y97.354 E0.00184 F600.000
G1 X99.100 Y97.327 E0.00229 F600.000
G1 X99.069 Y97.299 E0.00275 F600.000
G1 X99.038 Y97.272 E0.00321 F600.000
G1 X99.007 Y97.244 E0.00367 F600.000
G1 X98.976 Y97.216 E0.00413 F600.000
G1 X98.946 Y97.188 E0.00459 F600.000
G1 X98.915 Y97.160 E0.00505 F600.000
G1 X98.885 Y97.132 E0.00551 F600.000
G1 X98.855 Y97.103 E0.00596 F600.000
G1 X98.825 Y97.075 E0.00642 F600.000
```

**Cura generated code for above figure (Starting lines)**

```
G92 E0.00000
G1 E-2.00000 F3000.000
G1 Z3.160 F3000.000
G1 X99.257 Y97.462 F7200.000
G1 Z1.160 F3000.000
G1 E0.00000 F3000.000
G1 X39.300 Y64.450 E4.10919 F1200.000
G1 X39.300 Y35.550 E9.65851
G1 X60.700 Y35.550 E13.76770
G1 X60.700 Y64.450 E19.31703
G0 X60.500 Y64.450 F7200.000
G0 X60.500 Y64.350
G0 X59.610 Y63.360
G1 X40.390 Y63.360 E23.00762 F1200.000
G1 X40.390 Y36.640 E28.13834
G1 X59.610 Y36.640 E31.82893
G1 X59.610 Y63.360 E36.95966
G0 X41.085 Y62.863 F7200.000
G1 X40.884 Y62.663 E37.01410 F1200.000
G0 X40.884 Y61.107 F7200.000
G1 X42.640 Y62.863 E37.49095 F1200.000
G0 X44.196 Y62.863 F7200.000
G1 X40.884 Y59.551 E38.39034 F1200.000
G0 X40.884 Y57.996 F7200.000
G1 X45.751 Y62.863 E39.71200 F1200.000
G0 X47.307 Y62.863 F7200.000
G1 X40.884 Y56.440 E41.45619 F1200.000
G0 X40.884 Y54.884 F7200.000
G1 X48.863 Y62.863 E43.62293 F1200.000
G0 X50.418 Y62.863 F7200.000
G1 X40.884 Y53.329 E46.21193 F1200.000
G0 X40.884 Y51.773 F7200.000
G1 X51.974 Y62.863 E49.22347 F1200.000
G0 X53.530 Y62.863 F7200.000
G1 X40.884 Y50.218 E52.65742 F1200.000
G0 X40.884 Y48.662 F7200.000
G1 X55.085 Y62.863 E56.51377 F1200.000
G0 X56.641 Y62.863 F7200.000
G1 X40.884 Y47.106 E60.79265 F1200.000
G0 X40.884 Y45.551 F7200.000
G1 X58.197 Y62.863 E65.49394 F1200.000
G0 X59.114 Y62.226 F7200.000
G1 X40.884 Y43.995 E70.44452 F1200.000
G0 X40.884 Y42.439 F7200.000
G1 X59.114 Y60.670 E75.39510 F1200.000
G0 X59.114 Y59.114 F7200.000
G1 X40.884 Y40.884 E80.34554 F1200.000
G0 X40.884 Y39.328 F7200.000
G1 X59.114 Y57.559 E85.29612 F1200.000
G0 X59.114 Y56.003 F7200.000
G1 X40.884 Y37.772 E90.24670 F1200.000
G0 X41.802 Y37.135 F7200.000
G1 X59.114 Y54.447 E94.94785 F1200.000
G0 X59.114 Y52.892 F7200.000
G1 X43.357 Y37.135 E99.22674 F1200.000
G0 X44.913 Y37.135 F7200.000
G1 X59.114 Y51.336 E103.08309 F1200.000
G0 X59.114 Y49.781 F7200.000
G1 X46.468 Y37.135 E106.51717 F1200.000
G0 X48.024 Y37.135 F7200.000
G1 X59.114 Y48.225 E109.52871 F1200.000
G0 X59.114 Y46.669 F7200.000
G1 X49.580 Y37.135 E112.11771 F1200.000
G0 X51.135 Y37.135 F7200.000
G1 X59.114 Y45.114 E114.28445 F1200.000
G0 X59.114 Y43.558 F7200.000
G1 X52.691 Y37.135 E116.02864 F1200.000
G0 X54.247 Y37.135 F7200.000
G1 X59.114 Y42.002 E117.35030 F1200.000
G0 X59.114 Y40.447 F7200.000
G1 X55.802 Y37.135 E118.24969 F1200.000
G0 X57.358 Y37.135 F7200.000
G1 X59.114 Y38.891 E118.72654 F1200.000
G0 X59.114 Y37.335 F7200.000
G1 X58.914 Y37.135 E118.78085 F1200.000
G0 X58.914 Y37.135 Z2.320 F600.000
G0 X55.200 Y58.950 F7200.000
```

Answer (score 1):

Voxelizer is **multi-purpose software** that uses 5 to 7 different presets for the FAB and VX respectively. It decides upon what is available in options based on settings.

The **single and dual extruder setup** takes a whole load of data formats, including ones not commonly found in most other slicers:

[image]

The **paste extruder setup** and **Laser setup** only take `.dxf`, `.svg` and bitmap (`.jpg`, `.bmp`, `.png`) files:

[image]

The **CNC setup** features a different set of available extensions - including 2D files:

[image]

For a 3D model, use the extruder setups. It does not appear as if the software uses a special G-code format but works with derivates of the Marlin G-code library. To swap between setups, click in the top left corner, as you can see in this test-slice I ran:

[image]

Comment: Whether its possible to export GCode created in other slicing softwares are run in Zmorph printer ?

Comment: @PrithvirajV yes, the resulting G-code I got with similar settings in Voxelizer (for FDM settups, NOT paste) and from Cura is similar.